# Race conditions when using ViewProperyAnimators while testing with Espresso

Tags: android, android-animation, android-espresso

I have a simple Espresso test that's failing to assert visibility due to what I'd assume to be an animation issue. I have disabled all animation settings on the device.

```
bannerLayout.animate()
        .y(0)
        .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(1));
```

and my assertion in Espresso is

```
onView(withId(R.id.banner_layout)).check(matches(not(isDisplayed())));
```

Adding a sleep before the assertion makes the test pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that explicitly forcing the animation to start instead of relying on the framework to start it fixed the issue.

```
bannerLayout.animate()
    .y(0)
    .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(1))
    .start();
```

The [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html#start()) state:

> void start ()
>
> Starts the currently pending property animations immediately. Calling
> start() is optional because all animations start automatically at the
> next opportunity. However, if the animations are needed to start
> immediately and synchronously (not at the time when the next event is
> processed by the hierarchy, which is when the animations would begin
> otherwise), then this method can be used.

For simple animations, this should be fine. If you've got some complex scenario with performance concerns, this may not be the way to go.

Comment: Did you try disabling the animator in the dev settings?

Comment: @Be_Negative yep. That didn't seem to address this issue. Have also seen this when using the TransitionManager FWIW with all animations disabled.